# getting CORS and network error while calling axios post request using Vue js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, axios, cors

I am getting error while calling axios post request. But it works properly on postman.

[image]

The code I used for calling the request is

```
methods : {
     displayData(){
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/request/displayRequest',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        data : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.user._id))
        };

            axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            });
        },
    async mounted(){
        this.displayData()
    }
```

**I have already implemented CORS on the back-end in server.js**

```
// Cors Middleware
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => callback(null, true), // you can control it based on condition.
    credentials: true, // if using cookie sessions.
  })
);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Clijsters comments inside the code, are enough!

Answer (score 1):

in your backend use this  :

```
npm i cors
```

and in your express backend entrypoint:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
```

Comment: I have already used this code in the backend @babakabadkheir

Answer (score 0):

You are running your front-end on localhost and using some port. Also, your back-end is running on localhost, port 5000. But your front-end application can not access any other port due to CORS policy. You can solve this problem in the back-end if you are using Node JS.
Install [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) by the following command:

```
npm i cors
```

Then on your server file, change your app by

```
app.use(cors());
```

N.B. If you used React js, you could use [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware). Just create a file inside the src directory named "setupProxy.js". and add the following lines.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
    "/api",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:5000/",
    })
  );
};
```

Don't forget to change the port in this file into the port of your server.